# VBA code to find an item in a specific range and copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want the code to find a P/N in a list which is on Sheet3. Once the P/N is found in that range, its corresponding global P/N, brand, description and list price which are all on the same row as P/N has to be copied and added to Sheet 2 under similar headings. The P/N will already be added in Sheet 2. The below is the code that I have tried for this. But, there is a compile error coming as "Next without For" even though Next is added for all the corresponding For in the code.

```
Sub Price()

Dim pno As Double
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRowinMainSheet As Integer
Dim j As Integer

LastRowinMainSheet = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("E23"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

LastRow = Worksheets(3).UsedRange.SpecialCells(x1CellTypeLastCell).Row

For j = 24 To LastRowinMainSheet
Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 5).Value = pno

For i = 3 To LastRow
If Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = pno Then
Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Copy
Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Copy
Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 5).Copy
Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 14).Copy
Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 12).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next i

Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing an `End If`. In future please check your tags.

Comment: Indent your code - you will immediately see such problems.

Comment: I have added End if to my code now. Thanks for your suggestion. But, my code is still not working. The same Compile error "Next without For" keeps popping up.

Comment: You put the `End If` just before `Next i` I take it? Btw if you get in the habit of indenting your code it's easier to spot this sort of thing.

Comment: I have added End if and the Compile error has gone but another error is popping up Run time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error. Can you pls advise if there is anything else wrong with the code?

Comment: On which line? The `LastRowinMainSheet` line should have a worksheet reference. `SpecialCells` is not the way to find the last row.

Comment: `x1CellTypeLastCell` looks like you have digit 1 in there, it should be a letter 'l'.

Comment: Can you tell me what would be the code for finding the last blank row in a column starting with E23?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing end if

That'll have the same error msg within VBA.

edit 2021-03-25A
Alright, so without knowing the exact shape of your data, I think your looking something like this:

```
Sub Price()

Dim pno As Double
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRowinMainSheet As Integer
Dim j As Integer
                
LastRowinMainSheet = Worksheets(2).Cells(Worksheets(2).Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

LastRow = Worksheets(3).Cells(Worksheets(2).Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 24 To LastRowinMainSheet
    pno = Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 5).Value

    For i = 3 To LastRow
        If Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = pno Then
            Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Copy
            Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
            Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Copy
            Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
            Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 5).Copy
            Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
            Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 14).Copy
            Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 12).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
     Next i
Next j


End Sub
```

This work on my machine.

Beware that the entries for pno [col 5 in sheets(2) and col 2 in sheets(3)] currently must be numbers.

In your code, swapping:

```
LastRowinMainSheet = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("E23"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
```

to

```
LastRowinMainSheet = Worksheets(3).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("E23"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
```

also worked for me.

Comment: Adding in the end if and dummy values had it working here.

You did put the "end if " in before "next i" ?

Comment: Hi, yes, I've added the "end if" in before "next i". But, the same error keeps coming up "Application and object defined error". Please can you tell me what is wrong because i cant figure it out.

Comment: Have you stepped through it line by line with F8? Which line is the error coming on?

I wonder if your lastRowinMainSheet needs more specific instructions as to which worksheet it is addressing.

Comment: I have tried to go through line by line with F8 and I found that the error message keeps popping up at the first For loop. Do you know what the error here is?